# solutions $(x,y,z)$ where $x>y$, $y>z$, and $z>x$?

Tags: inequality

If I have the inequalities $x>y$, $y>z$, and $z>x$ and specify that the $x$ in equation one is equal to the $x$ in equation three, the $y$ in equation one is equal to the $y$ in equation two, and the $z$ in equation two is equal to the $z$ in equation three, are there any solutions to this problem?

Is this as much of a logical contradiction or does it just look like a logical contradiction?

Comment: The statements $x>y$ etc. are not *equations*. They are *inequalities*.

Answer (score 2):

Transitivity of well ordering prevents this to have any solutions.
$$ x > y \land y > z \implies x > z
$$
where $\land$ means "and" and $\implies$ means "implies". Then $x > z$. But $x \geq z \land x \leq z \implies x = z$, which contradicts $x > z \implies x \neq z$. Hence there are no solutions.